# How to filter variables through multiple conditionals

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I'm writing code that will assign rank to Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Players. The ranking formula is borrowed from chess (ELO Rating method) but it needs some adjustments to properly reflect BJJ. I have three conditional functions which the score must pass through so that it is updated properly:

`Elo_Score` is already calculated based on original formula and now the score must pass through ONE of the following functions to see if it needs adjustment.

```
def Weight_Age_Rank_Dif():
    """this functions checks for a certain weight, age AND rank difference 
    between two players. 
    (it will kick in if the difference is bigger than 10 kilos, 15 years, 
    AND 100 rating points; so think of it as a smaller, less experienced 
    older guy fighting a bigger, more experienced and much younger 
    opponent)."""

def Weight_Dif():
    """this function checks for a weight difference only (10 or more kilos 
    between opponents)"""

def Age_Dif():
    """this function checks for an age difference only (10 or more years between 
    two players AND at least one player over 50; so it would have no effect 
    between two guys who were 22 and 34)."""

# PRINT RESULTS
```

The idea behind these functions is to provide a cushion to the underdogs (smaller, less experienced or significantly older guys). If they win, they win more points and if they lose they lose less.

My question is how do we make sure that only ONE of the functions is executed? So if two players met all conditions for the first function than how do we make sure the code skips directly to the `# PRINT RESULTS` without touching the other two?

Also, each function has multiple conditional statements. For example in the `Weight_Age_Rank_Dif()` function there are 8 conditional statements. When one of these conditionals is met how can we make the code exit the function, skip the other two functions and go directly to `# PRINT RESULTS`?

I have tried to make the entire script into one giant conditional statement with a bunch of `elif` statements but it doesn't work because nested conditionals within `elif` statements throw an `UnboundLocalError` and it seems inefficient to put in a global variable each time.

Comment: There's no actual code here. It's very difficult to discuss what code should do without code.

Comment: You want to put your conditions in some kind of structure, like a dictionary or a class. Then test each the conditions in order in a loop, and if one matches execute the adjustment function that they 'guard', and then exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to put your conditions in some kind of structure, like a dictionary or a class. Then test each the conditions in order in a loop, and if one matches execute the adjustment function that they 'guard', and then exit the loop.

For example, you could put the conditions into functions too. Functions in Python are just more objects, you can put a function object in a list just like you can put other things in a list. A list is a good structure here because lists are *ordered*, so you can order the conditions.

Another option is to simply leave the condition testing to the function, and test if the score changed. If the ELO score changed, skip the other function(s), if not, continue. I'd still put the functions in a list first:

```
# list of score adjustment functions. Note that they are *not being called*,
# the function objects themselves are referenced here, not what they produce.
adjust_elo_score_functions = [Weight_Age_Rank_Dif, Weight_Dif, Age_Dif]

for adjustment_function in adjust_elo_score_functions:
    new_elo_score = adjustment_function(elo_score)
    if new_elo_score != elo_score:
        # score was adjusted, stop adjusting further
        elo_score = new_elo_score
        break

# PRINT RESULTS
```

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. One more question, the elo_score is not one variable but rather all possible outcomes of a match between A and B. In Brazilian Jiu Jitsu there can be 10 outcomes (5 for each player: win by submission, win by points, draw, lose by points and lose by submission). Should I put these these in a list as well?

Comment: @IgorTatarinov: you'd bundle up those in one object. That can be a dictionary, a tuple, a list or a custom class, whatever works best for your code. That way you can pass around the combined piece of information as one thing. A next step would be to handle adjustments like the ones you are doing here *as part of the class* that defines the ELO score details.

Comment: Hey Martijn, what if I just want to calculate the two outcomes that occur as a result of a match? So instead of calculating 10 possible outcomes and selecting only 2 each time (for example: A wins by point, B loses by points) is there a way to calculate only what happens? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know. I don't know the rules of scoring, sorry.